# How to send table formatted sql output using ssis

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, email, ssis

I need to run a sql query and get the output in outlook mail in a table format using SSIS 2008.

I have designed the SSIS package and wrote the below code in C# for getting the query output, but i couldn't able align the data in table format.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_7f59d09774914001b60a99a90809d5c5.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {

            Variables varCollection = null;
            string header = string.Empty;
            string message = string.Empty;
            var colSpace = 4;

            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::EmailMessage");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Job_Name");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Start_DateTime");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::End_DateTime");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Run_Duration");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Job_Status");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

            //Set the header message for the query result
            if (varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value == string.Empty)
            {
                header = "Execute SQL task output sent using Send Email Task in SSIS:\n\n";
                header += string.Concat("Job_Name".PadRight(40 + colSpace), "Start_DateTime".PadRight(15 + colSpace), "End_DateTime".PadRight(15 + colSpace), "Run_Duration".PadRight(15 + colSpace), "Job_Status".PadRight(100 + colSpace));
                varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value = header;
            }

            //Format the query result with tab delimiters
            message = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                                        varCollection["User::Job_Name"].Value,
                                        varCollection["User::Start_DateTime"].Value,
                                        varCollection["User::End_DateTime"].Value,
                                        varCollection["User::Run_Duration"].Value,
                                        varCollection["User::Job_Status"].Value);

            varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value = varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value + message;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

I need the output table with four columns in a table format in mail.

Comment: Why not use `sp_send_dbmail`, which supports HTML messages?

Comment: I don't have access to the sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: Yet you're required to send datasets out from SQL Server, via email, in HTML tables? It seems like you should; I would suggest talking to your DBA about that.

Comment: Why not create a SQL Report which produces HTML.  Then attach the HTML to your email.

Comment: @jdweng can you pls elaborate.

Comment: @Larnu i already checked with them, they are not ready to provide the access.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Email and SQL report are both HTML.  So you can create a SQL Report which is an email template and the just email the report.

Comment: Don't do this in SSIS.   Do it in SSRS.